# How to compare the elements of two arrays?

Tags: java

I want to compare the elements of one array with another to know if the first contains the elements of the other using Java.

```java
String[][] winnerPositions = new String[8][3];
ArrayList<String> positionsX = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> positionsO = new ArrayList<>();

private void definePositionsMatrix() {
        winnerPositions[0][0] = "195";
        winnerPositions[0][1] = "196";
        winnerPositions[0][2] = "197";

        winnerPositions[1][0] = "198";
        winnerPositions[1][1] = "199";
        winnerPositions[1][2] = "200";

        winnerPositions[2][0] = "201";
        winnerPositions[2][1] = "202";
        winnerPositions[2][2] = "203";
    }

private void validateWinner(String player, ArrayList<String> posPlayer, String[][] posWinner) {
        Log.i("arrayPositions: ", Arrays.toString(posPlayer.toArray()));
        // Log.i("qqq", posPlayer.toString().contains("195") + "");
        for (String[] strings : posWinner) {
            for (String string : strings) {
                try {
                    for (String s : posPlayer) {
                        if (s.equals(string)) {
                            Log.i("WINNER", "WINNER " + player);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log.i("CATCH", "Error " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

`posPlayer` is the array that I want to compare with `posWinner` to know if three elements of `posWinner` are found in `posPlayer`

I expect that if the player's array of positions contains any of the winning combinations, the method will return true.

Comment: have you heard of [.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you need a `try...catch` there?

Comment: So... which one is required condition - 1) Some array in `posWinner` need to contain all the strings in `posPlayer`. 2) Some array in `posWinner` need to contains at least one of the strings in `posPlayer`. 3) Some array in `posWinner` exactly contains strings in `posPlayer` ?

Comment: `the method will return true.` the method is defined as `void` so it cannot do this - modify signature to be `private boolean validateWinner(...)` and use your logic to return result.

Comment: `static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> lhs, Collection<T> rhs) {
    return lhs.size( ) == rhs.size( ) && lhs.containsAll(rhs)  && rhs.containsAll(lhs);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with the concepts of [Set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).
Your question then boils down to: are all the other array's elements contained in the first array?

So your check can be written as a function performing this:

1. For each element in the other array...
2. Try to find it in the first array
3. if not found, return false
4. return true

Answer (score 0):

```java
boolean winner = false;
for (String[] winComb : posWinner) {
    posWinSetBg = winComb;
    int count = 0;
    for (String posWin : winComb) {
        for (String pos : posPlayer) {
            if (pos.equals(posWin)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 3) {
        winner = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code solves your problem?